# Renaming several files using CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a special need and I feel stuck on that..
Some user will put some file in a directory with several different name, and I need to rename them regarding a special pattern for those files to be consume by another app.

Example:

In directory -> Target

file1-dd-mm-yyyy -> file1

file2 -> thisfile2

flie45224 -> file123

So as you can see this can be some variables, dates, ID etc..
The target will always be the same but the file in source can be different because of date for example.

So first I had 2 files, so I write the script in plain text "If test-path blabla do this else go out" but it seems that now I will have 37 different files with all differents name. So I thought about using an excel sheet(CSV?), but I can't really find any help on this need.

The goal is to have a sheet as "pattern" like if you found file like in 'A1' then rename as in 'A2' etc...
Do you guys have an idea ?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Can you show the current code (with many `if` statements)? Like, how do you get `file123` from `flie45224`?

Comment: `If(Test-Path -Path "C:\xxx\flie*.txt")
{Rename-Item -Path "C:\xxx\flie*.txt" -NewName 'file123.txt' }`

Comment: I modify it a bit but this is the idea. With an exit if this do not find any file.

Comment: That sounds like it's going to be a big problem if someone drops two files into the directory: `flie45224.txt` and `flie98765.txt` - now you have two files you want to rename to `file123.txt`, how do you intend to resolve that conflict?

Comment: Normally it shouldn't happen, those files are automated, but you right if this fail, I would have one file erased by the other. But then it can be solve by counting before applying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you need a csv with the following columns:

- A1: regex/pattern to match
- A2: transform rule which should be
  dynamic

The trick is to use `scriptblock` if you want to use variables like the file name.

Basically, your csv will be:

```
A1;A2
"^file1-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d$";"file1"
"^file2$";"this$($file.Name)"
"^flie*";"file123"
```

And the code would be:

```
$myRules = Import-Csv "C:\xxx\test.csv" -Delimiter ";"

$files = gci C:\temp\

foreach ($file in $files) {
    foreach ($rule in $myRules) {
        if ($file.Name -match $rule.A1) {
            Write-host "$($file.Name) is matching pattern ""$($rule.A1)"". Applying rename to ""$($rule.A2)"""
            $NewScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("rename-item -Path $($file.FullName) -NewName ""$($rule.A2)""")
            $NewScriptBlock.Invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives before:

```
file1-01-02-0344
file2           
flie45224
```

Output during the execution:

```
file1-01-02-0344 is matching pattern "^file1-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d$". Applying rename to "file1"
file2 is matching pattern "^file2$". Applying rename to "this$($file.Name)"
flie45224 is matching pattern "^flie*". Applying rename to "file123"
```

And after:

```
file1          
thisfile2
file123
```

**Explanations**

The first `foreach` is parsing the files. Then for each of those files, we are checking if one of the rule is matching thanks to the `-match $rule.A1`.

With the first example, you can use regexp (\d to match digits). *For the other cases, I kept it simple as you didn't clarify the rules but this will be your homework :)*

Then in the transform rules, you can use the filename variable as shown in the second transform rule: `this$($file.Name)`

NB: it could be a good idea to add a flag to leave the loop for the current file once it has been renamed to avoid unecessary check and to display a message if the file hasn't match any pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's nearly what I need, the issue I see are the files that come with an ID I can't control (different every days), I should be able to use à wildcard.. I wonder if powershell cmdlet will know how to read it through csv file...

Comment: If you put `"flie*";"file123"` in the csv file, it will matches all files containing flie*. But as mentionned in the comments by Mathias you must be careful is multiple file are matching the same pattern and if you use "static" transformation rule to avoid duplicates! If you need more help on this, maybe you can give more concrete examples of your patterns and transformation.

Comment: Alright, I just did my adaptation of you example, added some other variable and try on different files, it exactly match my needs :) 
I know how I will manage my transformation rules now, no duplicates should be created! thanks a lot for this great answer, I learned somthing new today!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit odd, I suspect you should be able to use a regex pattern instead but can't say without seeing the csv contents. Otherwise try this. Assumes the CSV has a column headers called First and Second, First matches the basename (no extension) of the file and Second contains the basename you want it changed to.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path c:\filenames.csv
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp | %{if($csv.First -contains $_.BaseName){Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($csv.Second[$csv.First.IndexOf($_.BaseName)]+$_.Extension)"}}
```